# Cant initialize MySQL. "mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqld, mysqld-safe

I am doing a fresh install of MySQL on Fedora 22.
After I run mysql_install_db I try to start the daemon using mysqld_safe but it does not work. The system says:

```
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

How do I get this to work?

Here are the mariadb.log contents:

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
[Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.23-MariaDB) starting as process 20443 ...
[Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
[ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
[ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> The system tablespace must be writable

Please check the permission of the data directory of MySQL

Comment: Checked. Its OK. mysql-server owns the directory.

Comment: Another permission check: Was mariadb being run as mysql?

Comment: @Computer the mysql user has to own the datadir, its content, and have access to the entire path (all parent dirs of the datadir). Do you maybe have apparmor or selinux active? These like to block mysql from accessing its files.

Comment: please provide the output of below command:

ls -ld /var/lib/mysql
and
ls -l /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 1):

`[ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
[ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
[ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!`

These imply a few potential causes to the issue.

1. The `mysql` user is not properly initiated on the host.
2. The `mysql` user does not own `/var/lib/mysql`.
3. The `/var/lib/mysql` directory does not have proper permissions for the `mysql` user.
4. The `/var/lib/mysql` directory does not exist and/or is full and therefore unwritable.

Making proper permissions to allow the `mysql` user to write onto the specified location will allow you to start `mysqld_safe` (as well as `mysqld`) successfully, assuming no other outstanding issues are present on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions of

- `/var/lib/mysql`
- `/var/run/mariadb`

Those folders have to be owned by `mysql` user

- `/tmp/`
  has to be global writable `+t`

  ```
  chmod 777 /tmp/
  chmod +t /tmp/
  chown root:root /tmp/

  $ ls -lahd /tmp/

  drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4,0K Okt 28 22:54 /tmp/
  ```